# Selenium - Unable to find the hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I am trying to create an framework where I want to find whether an webelement is hidden or not before performing an action on the web element.

I have a password field which is hidden and is structured as below

```
<div class=hidepassword>
  <input password field >
<div>
```

When I query the input tag with the following lines

```
Isvisible1 = (string)js1.ExecuteScript("return (window.getComputedStyle?window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null):arguments[0].currentStyle).visibility;", myCurElement);
                Isvisible2 = (string)js1.ExecuteScript("return (window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null).getPropertyValue('display'));", myCurElement);                    
                Isvisible3 = (bool)js1.ExecuteScript("return !(arguments[0].offsetHeight <= 1);", myCurElement);
```

I am getting all the values indicating it as visible.

Later , got to know that the class which the preceding div has is making the input invisible. 
I tried to get the value of overflow which is made available in the .css file for the class hidepassword

But unfortunately, there are lot of css values for the class hidepassword and when I use the below javascript function, I am able to get only one of its CSS value

```
 public string getStyle(string ClassName)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        return (String)js.ExecuteScript(
        "function getStyle(ClassName) {" +
            "var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;" +
            "var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;" +
            "for (var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++)" +
            "{" +
            "    var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;" +
            "    if (!classes)" +
            "        continue;" +
            "    var classesLength = classes.length;" +
            "    for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++)" +
            "    {" +
            "        if (classes[x].selectorText == ClassName)" +
            "        {" +
            "            var ret;" +
            "            if (classes[x].cssText)" +
            "            {" +
            "                ret = classes[x].cssText;" +
            "            }" +
            "            else" +
            "            {" +
            "                ret = classes[x].style.cssText;" +
            "            }" +
            "            if (ret.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1)" +
            "            {" +
            "                ret = classes[x].selectorText +   ret  ;" +
            "            }" +
            "            return ret;" +
            "        }" +                
            "    }" +                
            "}" +                
        "}return getStyle(arguments[0]);", ClassName);
    }
```

Is there a way to get all the css values for the particular class name and then based on the css values for the class, we can make a call whether the element is visible or not visible. ?

Thanks in advance for all your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium had supply api：isDisplayed() to detect element visibility, why you want to implement it as such complex by yourself

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This didnt work in my case. Though the element is not visible, Selenium tells that it is visible.

Comment: @Rajan, Could you tell me the computed style value of 'display'  of the div element in browser dev tool?   can you share your finding which controled the visibility of the div or input element,